# I am getting an error while uploading my Django app to server

Tags: python, django, heroku

```
2020-10-10T15:33:00.962648+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-10-10T15:33:01.005314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-10-10T15:33:01.408833+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=writingroom.herokuapp.com request_id=c6148721-26bb-4fac-83bf-4acd4ea1365b fwd="176.233.99.0" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
Restarting dynos on ⬢ writingroom... done
PS D:\visual_studio_code\python1\django\my_blog> heroku open
```

[image]

I am getting an error while uploading my Django app to server(error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" )

Comment: Show some code please, the Proc file and the main app file

Answer (score 1):

I think that Heroku is so Hard for Deploying or for config. you can using [pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) this platform can help you for deploying Django, Flask or any project which is making by Python Frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Check out and see if you've used up all your free dyno hours.